# Div placement in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like it to create the div where the mouse is. I have the following code:

```
var mouseisdown = false;

$(document).mousedown(function(event) {
 mouseisdown = true;
 doSomething();
 }).mouseup(function(event) {
 mouseisdown = false;
});

function doSomething(e){
    var draw = document.createElement("div");
    draw.className = "draw";
    document.body.appendChild(draw);
    draw.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
    draw.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
if (mouseisdown)
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery create div on mouseclick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642277/jquery-create-div-on-mouseclick)

Comment: You might want to look into [using mousemove](http://jsfiddle.net/jv9e9qtd/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you already had it, but you overcomplicated it:

- Remove the `mouseisdown` variable and the event listeners
- Add `doSomething` as a click event listener
- Don't call `doSomething` recursively

```js
$(document).click(function doSomething(e){
  var draw = document.createElement("div");
  draw.className = "draw";
  document.body.appendChild(draw);
  draw.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
  draw.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
});
```

```css
.draw {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: -5px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click somewhere
```